# interpreting assumption tests for multilevel modelling

Tags: r, logistic, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I have run a multilevel logistic regression model using the glme package in R. I now need to test the assumptions but I am not sure how to interpret the graphs I get, nor whether I'm doing the correct assumption tests.

Some background:
my outcome variable is binary (spelling accuracy: 1= correct, 0= incorrect)
my predictors are all continuous and are all characteristics of the items (Words)
I have 2 crossed random effects: participants (97) and items (20 words used in the spelling task)

All participants had to spell all 20 words.

My model code is as follows:

```
M1 <-glmer(spelling_accuracy ~ 1 + OLD20 + OLDF + wordlength_letter + word_frequency + (1|items) + (1|participants), data = combined_df, family= binomial)
```

1. It's a non-linear model so I don't test for the assumption of linearity (right?)
2. For homogeneity of variance I ran a fitted vs residuals plot

```
plot(M1)
```

This is the outcome, how do I interpret this? It looks like a clear violation but not sure what's happening, or what I can do to fix it.

[image]

3. I then tested that the residuals are normally distributed

```
qqnorm(resid(M1), main="Q-Q plot for conditional residuals")

qqnorm(ranef(M1)$items$`(Intercept)`, 
      main="Q-Q plot for the random intercept")
```

Which gave me the following:

[image]

Still unsure how to interpret these, but I think they look relatively normal?

Are there any other tests I have to run? And from these tests would I have to transform my data in some way first before using the model?

Would really appreciate the help as I am way out of my depth here.

Comment: You are checking some assumptions for linear regression that logistic regression does not have. This page may be of some help: https://www.statology.org/assumptions-of-logistic-regression/

Comment: try the `DHARMa` package ...